# In scope - is this a hoax

Tags: discussion, scope

Would this is a hoax be an answer or is the question out of scope?

[hydrogen-in-a-gas-tank](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/14700/hydrogen-in-a-gas-tank)

Answer (score 7):

Proving, disproving, or simply rejecting these claims is outside the scope of this site. We've looked at similar situations before:

[Could we make a space for disproving popular life-hacks?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/could-we-make-a-space-for-disproving-popular-life-hacks/1296#1296)

So this would be **off topic.**

> This may be on topic on our Skeptics site — please see the [Help Center](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help) to check — however, this type of myth-buster fact-checking is outside the scope of *this* site.